# Using projected points from Linear Discriminant Analysis to generate probability density function

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, density-function, discriminant-analysis

I am using Linear Discriminant Analysis technique to get the best possible separation between two distributions. I am using R for my programming.

For LDA, I find the **between-class scatter matrix(B)** and **within-class scatter matrix(W)**. The discriminant axis is the first eigen-vector of $W^{-1}B$.

```
    #Center the data
    centeredData <- scale(data[,1:2], scale = FALSE)

    # Generating Scatter matrices
    B <- betweenCov(variables = data[,1:2], group = data$Class)
W <- withinCov(variables = data[,1:2], group = data$Class)

    # Finding the Eigen vectors
    ev <- eigen(solve(W) %*% B)$vectors
    slope <- - ev[1,1] / ev[2,1]
    intercept <- ev[2,1]

    # Create projections on 1st discriminant
    projectedPoints <- centeredData %*% ev[,1] %*% t(ev[,1])
```

After projecting points on the discriminant axis, I plot the points. The following plot generated shows the separation obtained by LDA. [image: LDA Projection]

As you can see, both the distributions are clearly separated and there is no overlap between them.

After projection of points, I separate them out into two distributions based on the class. **projectedPointsClass1** and **projectedPointsClass2** are two distributions projected on the discriminant axis

I use **density()** function from the stats package in R to get the densities,

```
  #Get densities of both classes
  densityClass1 = density(projectedPointsClass1)      
  densityClass2 = density(projectedPointsClass2)      

  #Plot the densities
  plot(range(densityClass1$x, densityClass2$x), range(densityClass1$y, densityClass2$y), 
       type = "n", xlab = "x",ylab="Density")
  lines(d1, col="red")
  lines(d2, col="blue")
```

[image: Density Plot]

This is something irregular. I am not sure why the densities of both the distributions overlap. There is no overlap in the distributions(as seen in the 1st plot), but there is an overlap in the density plots.

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Also, please let me know if I am doing something which is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the data and/or code you used to generate each of these plots, but based on the density plot, it isn't clear that LDA is an appropriate method (assuming that the density plot is correct). You have two distributions, each of which are themselves bimodal. LDA assumes you are separating two normally distributed components. So if that density plot is accurate, LDA simply isn't an appropriate method. However, it seems to me naively that you may have made a mistake producing one or both of these plots.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thank you for your help and feedback. I have included the code I use to find the discriminant, and find density and plot it. Is there something wrong I am doing here?